# Find an object with an attribute value within a collection of objects in groovy

Tags: object, variables, groovy, scope, scriptrunner-for-jira

I have a collection of type ProjectComponent, I am using the following code to find an object in my collection with a specific name. Here is the code:

```
 if(newIssueproject.getComponents().stream().anyMatch { it.getName().equals(shortenedComponentName)  }){
                        newComponent=it
   }
```

I am receiving the error **Script function failed on Automation for Jira rule: UpdateExecutionSummary , file: SuperFeature/rest_superFeatureGenerator.groovy, error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: it for class: SuperFeature.rest_superFeatureGenerator**

But I have looked up tutorials and the it should work automatically even if it is not declared as you can see here:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use Groovy synthax? It has `.find` method for collections, which is way more laconic and expressive than Java streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first use of `it` should work fine.  This is probably fine:

```
newIssueproject.getComponents().stream().anyMatch { 
   it.getName().equals(shortenedComponentName)  
})
```

The second one is not defined.

```
if(newIssueproject.getComponents().stream().anyMatch { it.getName().equals(shortenedComponentName)  }){
    newComponent=it   // it's me.  I'm the problem it's me.
}
```

If you want to grab the component you're after I might do this:

```
newIssueProject.components.stream()
    .findFirst { it.name == shortedComponentName }
    .ifPresent { component ->
       // do something with it
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line: `newComponent=it`.
You're using `it` in the scope, where it is not defined. The `it` variable is only "visible" inside the `anyMatch {...}` closure. What you need to do is, first, find the element, then assign. Here is the draft (using Java streams):

```
def found = newIssueproject.getComponents().stream().filter { it.getName().equals(shortenedComponentName) }.findAny()
newComponent = found.orElseGet(null)
```

Although, I'd recommend using Groovy syntax:

```
def found = newIssueproject.getComponents().find { it.getName() == shortenedComponentName) }
if (found) {
    newComponent = found
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: The code is still erroneous but it's on the right track, here is the right code `def found = newList.any { it.getName().equals(shortenedComponentName)}
                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA found--"+found+"--")

                    if(found ){
                        newComponent=projectComponentManager.findByComponentName(newIssueproject.getId(), shortenedComponentName)
                    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
 def found = newList.any { it.getName().equals(shortenedComponentName)}
                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA found--"+found+"--")

                    if(found ){
                        newComponent=projectComponentManager.findByComponentName(newIssueproject.getId(), shortenedComponentName)
                    }
```